# rebel.xml is not placed on resources folder

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jrebel

Good afternoon in my timezone.

In the Intellij IDE when i add the rebel.xml file throught the context menu, the file is created in the `*\src\main\java` folder when i want to be created at resources folder.
I am using maven.
Can anyone help on this one ?

Best regards
Thanks in advance

Comment: It work fine for me rebel.xml is created in resources folder. What version of Intellij IDEA are you using?

Comment: the jrebel plugin is the 6.5.1 and Intellij is 2016.1.1 , the resources folder is mark as resources either

Comment: jrebel plugin 6.5.1 and Intellij 2016.2.3 for me

Answer (score 2):

Check zeroturnaround quick start

https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/quickstart/intellij/#!/project-configuration

> In Intellij IDEA 2016.1.1 open **View** > **Tool Windows** > **JRebel**. The JRebel Modules window opens.

Use JRebel modules to generate rebel.xml

[image: JRebel modules]

Comment: I use that , but the file rebel.xml is generated at src/main/java instead , it should be generated at resources folder

Answer (score 0):

For some reason in ItelliJ settings/plugins the Maven Integration was disable, i enable it and stars work correctly

Thanks everyone